# using .net custom classes within matlab

Tags: .net, class, matlab

I'm currently using Matlab to import a custom dot NET dll library I have,
using `AssemblyInfo = NET.addAssembly('c:\myClasses.dll')`.

listing `disp(AssemblyInfo.Classes)` expose the custom classes of the library, like

```
'MyLib.ClassA'  
'MyLib.ClassB'  
'MyLib.ClassA+eResults'
```

I'm using `myVar = MyLib.ClassA;` to create a .net class variable within matlab (which works fine),
but the second class has no constructor, so `myVar = MyLib.ClassB;` results in
`No constructor 'MyLib.ClassB' with matching signature found.`

The second issue is the plus sign (+) at the .NET class `MyLib.ClassA+eResults`,
of which causing an error when I try `myVar = MyLib.ClassA+eResults;`
`Undefined function or variable 'eResults'.`

Is there a way to create an instance custom class `MyLib.ClassB` within matlab?
What is the plus sign means, and how do I create an instance of `MyLib.ClassA+eResults` without any syntax error?

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of `ClassA` and `CalssB`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create an instance of a class, it must be public and have public constructors. If the classB has only a custom constructor with multiple parameters, you can instantiate it like this:

```
var = MyLib.ClassB(x, y);
```

for the second issue, the + means eResults is a [nested class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23h0937%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of ClassA. You can't instantiante directly, but there is a workaround based on reflection described here: [Working With Nested Classes](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/matlab_external/getting-started-with-net.html#bsxjary-1):

```
a = NET.addAssembly('c:\myClasses.dll');
t = a.AssemblyHandle.GetType('MyLib.ClassA+eResults');
var = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```